# Android - Adding data to database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android application with **firebase** as my database. I want to insert some data on the press of a `button`, but some of the objects I want to insert in the database, is placed in **different methods** in my fragment. How can I insert data to my database across different methods using the **same button**?

```
public class mFragment extends Fragment implements 
DateFragment.DatePickerEvent {

DatabaseReference database;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
EditText text1;
EditText text2;

@Override
public void onDateSelected(String date) {
    Button buttonDateText = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
    buttonDateText.setText(date);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag, container, false);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Persons");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    Button pickDateButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
    Button submitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    text1= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.oddsView);
    text2= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.betAmountView);

    pickDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DateFragment picker = new DateFragment();
            picker.setDatePickerEvents(mFragment.this);
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            database.child("Person").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String myText= text1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String myAnotherText= text2.getText().toString().trim();
                    String id = database.push().getKey();
                    database.child(user.getDisplayName()).child(id).child("Adress").setValue(myText);
                    database.child(user.getDisplayName()).child(id).child("name").setValue(myAnotherText);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


}
```

The implemented interface comes from a datefragment I have made, where the user can choose a date on a date-widget. I want to insert the date object into the database, but I am unsure on how to do that with the submitButton being in another method

Comment: Give more clarity.. What exactly you want to achieve?!!

Comment: There is a submitButton which adds two textfields to database as a child of an unique id. In another method "onDateSelected" there is a date object, which i also want to add to the database as a child of the same unique id as the two textfields. All this should be done with the submitButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set the date to your `Button` using `buttonDateText.setText(date);` you can add this to your `onDataChange` and read it :

```
Button buttonDateText = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
String date = buttonDateText.getText().toString();
```

or declare a `String` as class variable `String mDate ="";`, inside `onDateSelected` do `mDate = date`, now you can use `mDate` inside your `onDataChange`